# Sub Totals and Total using linq for data contained in dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a dictionary wth a View Order as the key and the value is an object containing data incl. view order, type, testName, testGUSelected. The data looks like dictionary is soted

```
10, [10, A, English1, No];
12, [12, B, English1, Yes];
14, [14, C, English1, No];
16, [16, C, English1, No];
20, [20, B, English1, No];
22, [22, C, English1, No];
24 [24, C English1, No];
40 [40, A, English1, No];
42, [42, B, English1, No];
45,  [45, C, English1, Yes];
```

I need to calculate the number of 'C's belonging to it's parent 'B' and also also a count of 'B's belonging to their parent 'A'. 
The way to determine which C's belong to a particular 'B' is that the C's come after the B and their view order is greater than the parent 'B' and the child list continues till you hit the next B in the dictionary.
The way to determine which B's belong to a particular 'A' is that the B's come after the 'A' and their view order is greater than the parent 'A' and the child list continues till you hit the next A in the dictionary.

I need to calculate if the the number of 'C's belonging to it's parent 'B' and and check if all the C's belonging to a parent 'B' are marked 'Yes' then update the value of the parent 'B' from 'No' to 'Yes'. The same kind of calculation and update needs to happen for child'B' and parent 'A'.

Any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated.
Thanks for all your help, in advance.

Comment: Can you use a different data structure?  Preferably a tree.

Comment: I don't think a `Dictionary` is guaranteed to be sorted, so you'll have to use a different structure.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of things to improve on here, but what you'll want to do is get your data sorted and into a tree structure.  Then just loop through the child nodes to see if their values are set to Yes, and adjust the current node.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Load your data
        Dictionary<int, Data> data = new Dictionary<int, Data>(10);
        data.Add(10, new Data(10, Data.ViewType.A, "English1", Data.Selected.No));
        data.Add(12, new Data(12, Data.ViewType.B, "English1", Data.Selected.Yes));
        data.Add(14, new Data(14, Data.ViewType.C, "English1", Data.Selected.No));
        data.Add(16, new Data(16, Data.ViewType.C, "English1", Data.Selected.No));
        data.Add(20, new Data(20, Data.ViewType.B, "English1", Data.Selected.No));
        data.Add(22, new Data(22, Data.ViewType.C, "English1", Data.Selected.No));
        data.Add(24, new Data(24, Data.ViewType.C, "English1", Data.Selected.No));
        data.Add(40, new Data(40, Data.ViewType.A, "English1", Data.Selected.No));
        data.Add(42, new Data(42, Data.ViewType.B, "English1", Data.Selected.No));
        data.Add(45, new Data(45, Data.ViewType.C, "English1", Data.Selected.Yes));

        List<int> sortedViewOrder = data.Keys.ToList<int>();
        sortedViewOrder.Sort();
        Tree dataTree = new Tree(new TreeNode(new Data(0, Data.ViewType.A, "English1", Data.Selected.No)));
        //Assuming all your data is correctly ordered and A always has at least one B below it, B always has at least one C below it.
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedViewOrder.Count; )
        {
            TreeNode subTreeA = new TreeNode(data[sortedViewOrder[i]]);
            i++;
            while (i < data.Count && data[sortedViewOrder[i]].Type == Data.ViewType.B)
            {
                TreeNode subTreeB = new TreeNode(data[sortedViewOrder[i]]);
                i++;
                while (i < data.Count && data[sortedViewOrder[i]].Type == Data.ViewType.C)
                {
                    subTreeB.AddChild(new TreeNode(data[sortedViewOrder[i]]));
                    i++;
                }
                subTreeA.AddChild(subTreeB);
            }
            dataTree.Root.AddChild(subTreeA);
        }
        foreach (TreeNode childA in dataTree.Root.Children)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode childB in childA.Children)
            {
                if (childB.AllChildrenTestGUSelectedYes())
                {
                    childB.Data.TestGUSelected = Data.Selected.Yes;
                }
            }
            if (childA.AllChildrenTestGUSelectedYes())
            {
                childA.Data.TestGUSelected = Data.Selected.Yes;
            }
        }
        foreach (TreeNode childA in dataTree.Root.Children)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(childA.Data.ToString());
            foreach (TreeNode childB in childA.Children)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(childB.Data.ToString());
                foreach (TreeNode childC in childB.Children)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(childC.Data.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class Tree
    {
        public TreeNode Root { get; private set; }
        public Tree(TreeNode root)
        {
            Root = root;
        }
    }

    public class TreeNode
    {
        public Data Data { get; private set; }
        public List<TreeNode> Children { get; private set; }
        public TreeNode(Data data)
        {
            Data = data;
            Children = new List<TreeNode>();
        }
        public void AddChild(TreeNode child)
        {
            Children.Add(child);
        }
        public bool AllChildrenTestGUSelectedYes()
        {
            if (Children.Count == 0)
            {
                return Data.TestGUSelected == Data.Selected.Yes;
            }
            bool allChildrenYes = true;
            foreach (TreeNode child in Children)
            {
                if (!child.AllChildrenTestGUSelectedYes())
                {
                    allChildrenYes = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return allChildrenYes;
        }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public int ViewOrder { get; set; }
        public ViewType Type { get; set; }
        public string TestName { get; set; }
        public Selected TestGUSelected { get; set; }
        public Data(int viewOrder, ViewType type, string testName, Selected testGUSelected)
        {
            ViewOrder = viewOrder;
            Type = type;
            TestName = testName;
            TestGUSelected = testGUSelected;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "viewOrder:" + ViewOrder + " type:" + Type + " testName:" + TestName + " testGUSelected:" + TestGUSelected;
        }

        public enum ViewType
        {
            A, B, C
        }

        public enum Selected
        {
            Yes, No
        }
    }
}
```